# R : how do I run a Diebold Mariano test with a recursive pseudo out-of-sample forecasting exercise?

Tags: r, forecasting

I am currently running in R two forecasting models in a pseudo out-of-sample forecasting exercise. My horizon is 18 months and I get a total of 31 sequences of forecasts for each model.
Therefore, I obtain for each model a Forecasts Error matrix of dimension 18x31 (one forecast error for each horizon of each sequence).

How am I now supposed to implement the Diebold-Mariano test in order to compare the forecasting performance of both models ? Should I run one DM test for each horizon of each sequence ? or one DM test for each horizon ? or even only one test for the whole matrix ? I already tried those options with the `dm.test` function of the `forecast` package in vain... Here is one example of my many attempts:

```
for (i in 1:18) {
+      dm_test = dm.test(as.matrix(forecast_errors_Model1[i,]),
+                        as.matrix(forecast_errors_Model2[i,]),
+                        power = 2, h = 18)
+ }
Warning messages:
1: In dm.test(as.matrix(forecast_errors_Model1[i, ]), as.matrix(forecast_errors_Model2[i,  :
  Variance is negative, using horizon h=1
2: In dm.test(as.matrix(forecast_errors_Model1[i, ]), as.matrix(forecast_errors_Model2[i,  :
  Variance is negative, using horizon h=1
3: In dm.test(as.matrix(forecast_errors_Model1[i, ]), as.matrix(forecast_errors_Model2[i,  :
  Variance is negative, using horizon h=1
```

Could somebody please help figure this out and also maybe provide some piece of code that could help me understand the logic, it would be a great help !

Thank you very much.

Comment: What type of analysis did you conduct? ARIMA? ETS? Regression? If it's a method with statistical assumptions, like ARIMA, I'll make a wild stab in the dark and say that the assumptions probably weren't met. Try using `power = 1`. This math for this function is `d = c(abs(model1))^power - c(abs(model2))^power; d.cov = acf(d, lag.max = h-1, type = "covariance", plot = F)$acf[, , 1]; dv = sum(c(d.cov[1], 2 * d.cov[-1]))/length(d)` the Diebold- Mariano statistic is then `mean(d)/sqrt(df)`. You can't have a negative value here.

Comment: Hi @Kat, I'm using multiple models and among those I'm testing there are indeed a SARIMA model, a Holt-Winters model but also a model that I have build on my own.
I tried power = 1, but there is still the same error that appears. If I set h = 1, the problem seems to disappear but I don't think that it is the right way to do as the forecast horizon is 18.

Comment: Try switching the order of the models: `dm_test = dm.test(as.matrix(forecast_errors_Model2[i,]), as.matrix(forecast_errors_Model1[i,]),power = 2, h = 18)` Also, try a few outside of the loop, to make sure it's not something off about the data structure versus the actual model comparison.